# Phone only works with busted battery

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. A few days ago I noticed that the phone shut down on it's own, but when I plugged it to a charger it showed that the battery still had 20%. When I removed the battery I noticed that it is slightly swollen. Those look like signs of a busted battery to me.

Now, I bought a replacement, put it in, but the phone doesn't start or charge (not even the red diode is lighting). I've taken my phone to the store where I bought the replacement thinking that I got a broken battery, but the seller tested 2 other batteries (one no-name brand and one original Samsung battery), but neither worked. What does work however is the busted battery. I want to continue using my S3, but I'm at a loos as to how to fix it.

My best guess is that the battery level meter in the phone got decalibrated by the busted battery and the voltage levels on the good ones way too different for it to work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found out why my new battery isn't working, it had a transparent sticker on the power pins (and only on the pins). It was virtually invisible in broad daylight and there was no indicator on the package anywhere that there is such a sticker there (much less that it needs to be removed). It was only when I looked on the battery at a certain angle with electric light that I noticed it.

I'm not an expert on mobile phones and I change phone batteries pretty much never, so maybe that sticker there is common knowledge for everybody else, but the funny thing is, the guy at the shop where I bought the new battery didn't notice it either (and he should have been an expert).

Comment: Haha, wow. They should definitely make it more clear that that sticker is there.